# 404 error in the header area which is for google fonts

Tags: wordpress, error-handling, http-status-code-404

Today I found some error in my website.  They are 404 error not found.  This is located in the header of WordPress in the homepage.

```
<link rel='dns-prefetch' href='//fonts.googleapis.com' />
<link href='https://fonts.gstatic.com' crossorigin rel='preconnect' />
```

I have tried looking for them on the source but I did not find them.  The site has a child theme, in WordPress.  I do not know why it says 404 error.

Please help me, do I need to delete these links just to get rid of that error?

Comment: this is the code that has error 
https://www.screencast.com/t/AByitfIq

and this is the error of the code
https://www.screencast.com/t/0uo5XsmQOEpf

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/